# Getting columnnames and then replace it into rs.getString()?

Tags: java, sqlite, resultset

I am connecting to a sqlite database and grabbing all the columnnames. What i need help with is by putting those columnnames in rs.getString and inserting the values which are grabbed in a String Array which then can be set on the tablemodel.

My code now:

```
 stmt = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
  int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

 // The column count starts from 1
 for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
 String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
 System.out.println(name);
 // Do stuff with name
 model.setColumnCount(i);


 }

  while ( rs.next() ) {
    String value1 = "";
      String value2 = "";
        String value3 = "";
          String value4 = "";
     value1 = rs.getString("SNO");
     value2 = rs.getString("SNAME");
     value3 = rs.getString("STATUS");
     value4 = rs.getString("CITY");


     model.addRow(new Object[] { value1,value2,value3,value4});

  }
```

What i would want it to be:

```
  stmt = c.createStatement();
  ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);

  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
  int columnCount = rsmd.getColumnCount();

  // The column count starts from 1
   for (int i = 1; i < columnCount + 1; i++ ) {
    String name = rsmd.getColumnName(i);
    System.out.println(name);
   // Do stuff with name
   model.setColumnCount(i);


  }

  while ( rs.next() ) {
   String values[];
   values[] = rs.getString(name);        

     model.addRow(new Object[] {values[]});

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't keep calling `model.setColumnCount(i);`. Just set it once (outside the for loop), like this `model.setColumnCount(columnCount);` Also

```
// Do stuff with name
model.setColumnCount(i); // Not this...

// Do stuff with name
model.setColumnName(i, name); // Something like this... that is set the name
```

Comment: Those are good advices thanks! but i think you misunderstood my question. What i need done is instead of having value1 = rs.getString("SNO"); etc. I would like to replace "SNO" with the name String. and then have a Array that grabs all the data.

Comment: Instead of: value1=rs.getString("sno");                                                             I would like: values[] = rs.getString(name);

Comment: Yes. `value1 = rs.getString(model.getColumnName(i));`

Comment: I tried your line but it didn't work :/ it gives me error. no column F exists.